# Удалить ссылку регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, wordpress, изображения, link

На страницах сайта WordPress присутствует ненужная ссылка, которая ведёт на страницу вложений.

**Вот как выглядит ссылка в содержании:**

```
<a href="http://site.ru/content.html/pageimage" rel="attachment wp-att-8516">
<img class="size-full wp-image-8516" src="http://site.ru/images/2015/12/image.png" alt="" height="299" width="601">
</a>
```

**Регулярное выражение для удаление этой ссылки:**

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );
function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
 $content =
 preg_replace(
 array('{<a(.*?)(attachment wp-att|images)[^>]*><img}',
 '{wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
 array('<img','" />'),
 $content
 );
 return $content;
 }
```

С этим выражением есть две проблемы которые я не смог решить.

Не удаляется закрывающий тег `</a>`

```
<img class="size-full wp-image-8516" src="http://site.ru/images/2015/12/image.png" alt="" height="299" width="601">
 </a>
```

Вторая проблема, удаляются ссылки совсем другого вида:

```
<a class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)" href="http://site.ru/images/image.jpg">
<img src="http://site.ru/images/image_tr.png" height="93" width="125">
</a>
```

И, так же не удаляется закрывающий тег `</a>`

```
<img src="http://site.ru/images/image_tr.png" height="93" width="125">
</a>
```

Помогите пожалуйста доделать регулярное выражение, чтобы удалялся закрывающий тег `</a>` и не удалялись ссылки с классом **highslide**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой путь, подразумевающий что все подобные ссылки не поменяют свой вид:

```
preg_replace(
    '/<a[^>]+rel="attachment[^"]*">(.*?)<\/a>/',
    '$1',
    $content
);
```

Недостаток в том, что парсить/преобразовывать HTML фрагменты *при помощи регулярных выражений* не очень правильно. Врядли вы сможете учесть все варианты контента. При этом может нарушиться разметка страницы, которую выдает CMS.

Правильный путь:

1. Распарсить контент в виде DOM-фрагмента;
2. Найти нужные ссылки;
3. Заменить найденные ссылки на их содержимое.

Comment: На данный момент это регулярное выражение вполне подходит. Спасибо. На будущие надо запомнить: что картинки это не ссылка, ну или в крайнем случае.